# Raw data (bytes) and signed/unsigned variables

Tags: c++, c, byte, eof, unsigned

I've been told that whenever you work with bytes, you should declare your variables as unsigned chars.
In Windows' data types, BYTE is declared as an unsigned char.

My questions:

Why?

Unsigned is a representation of integers from 0 to 255 and signed 128 to -127.

**If that's the case, then how is EOF in binaries (-1) caught?**

EOF is declared in stdio.h as a -1 #define macro.

Comment: EOF isn't a real character, it is just a return value with the meaning that no more input is available.

Comment: @Theolodis - EOF in stdio.h is declared as #ifndef EOF
# define EOF (-1)
#endif

Comment: It's implementation-dependent if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`. Also, `EOF` is an `int` and not a `char`. If you assign `EOF` to a `char` and compare it to the `int` value `EOF` they will not match, because the compiler will extend the `char` to `0x000000ff` which is not the same as the `int` value `0xffffffff` (using the normal [two's complement value of `-1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

Comment: Yep, but you would never parse it into a byte, as it is not in the range of a byte. And why unsigned char? because a byte has 8 bit, giving you the range of 0 to 255.

Comment: @AndyCarter Read http://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Depends, if `char` is signed then [it works](http://ideone.com/c9wcTy). That's what's so horrid about the signedness of `char` not being defined :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. If `char` is signed, and the encoding is ISO 8859-1,
then checking for `EOF` on a `char` will return true if you
input a `'ÿ'`.  It's always an error to assign the return value
of a `getc()`, `fgetc` or `std::istream::get()` to a `char` (or
an `unsigned char`) before having checked for `EOF`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree it's an error, I was just highlighting the issue of behavior defined on signedness of the type. It's infuriating that such a basic two-ways conversion result may change...

Answer (score 3):

When you read chars from a stream, the return type of functions like [`std::getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) is `int`, and not `char`. The constant [EOF](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Macros) is of type `int`, and not `char` or `unsigned char`.

Even in the C++ I/O API, the I/O streams like [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) deal with types `char_type` (that is the type of characters in the stream), and `int_type` that is a [type that can hold all values of `char_type`, plus `EOF`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits).

Answer (score 1):

EOF is a status information, and is distinct from the data. However some functions have habit of using single return type for both. Example:

```
/* Return next data byte (0 - 255) or EOF (-1) if there was an error */
int readByte(...);
```

Point is that you need to have larger type than plain byte to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You use `EOF` with functions like `getchar()` which return int. So it is possible to map legal values of int(0 to 255) to char(0 to 255) and still differentiating EOF int(-1)

Quoting from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) about return value of getchar.

> On success, the character read is returned (promoted to an int value).
>   The return type is int to accommodate for the special value EOF, which
>   indicates failure: If the standard input was at the end-of-file, the
>   function returns EOF and sets the eof indicator (feof) of stdin. If
>   some other reading error happens, the function also returns EOF, but
>   sets its error indicator (ferror) instead.

Answer (score 1):

fgetc (one of the basic function that can returns EOF) is declared to return an integer.

When you look into the CRT functions, than you can see that all  functions that can return EOF have an int signature.

So in fact you have always a truncation to char, when using fgetc and store the result in a char.

There is no great difference between unsigned char, and char. The real difference is when the compiler converts it to an int. In one case you have a sign extension in the other case (unsigned) you don't have it.